# RegEx: match all occurrences of X not enclosed by Y

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is it possible to create a regular expression of a pattern X that is not enclosed by a pattern Y using `preg_match` in PHP?

for example, consider this string:

```
hello, i said <a>hello</a>
```

I want a regex that matches the first hello but not the second... I couldn't think of anything

Comment: What regex engine are you using? And have you thought about using negated characters like `[^...]`?

Comment: @Jerry it's php's preg_match

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look behind lookup:

```
(?<!<a>)hello
```

Comment: + negative lookahead actually ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Assuming your use case is a bit more complex then `hello, i said <a>hello</a>`; then if you where looking for all the `hello` in `hello, i said <a>after arriving say hello</a>` you might want to just capture the good and bad, then use some programming logic to process only the matches you're interested in.

This expression will capture all the `<a>...</a>` sub strings and all the `hello` strings. Since the undesirable substring is matched first if the desirable substring appears inside then it won't ever be included in the capture group 1.

`<a>.*?<\/a>|\b(hello)\b`

[image]

## Example

Live example: http://ideone.com/jpcqSR

**Sample Text**

```
Chello said Hello, i said <a>after arriving say hello</a>
```

**Code**

```
$string = 'Chello said Hello, i said <a>after arriving say hello</a>';
$regex = '/<a>.*?<\/a>|\b(hello)\b/ims';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

foreach($matches as $key=>$value){
    if ($value[1]) {
        echo $key . "=" . $value[0];
    }
        }
```

**Output**

Note the upper case `H` in hello shows that it was the desired substring.

```
0=Hello
```